# Varnish - TTL and the current Date

Tags: varnish

I'd like to set the TTL based on the current date.

http://site.com/2011/03/ should have 5 days as TTL.
http://site.com/2011/04/ should have 1 day as TTL.
Current Date: 15 April 2011

How is this possible in varnish?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution is to set the headers appropriately in the backend instances.

E.g., set `Cache-Control; max-age=...` on each backend response. Varnish takes this header information into account when computing the TTL.